# Excel VBA worksheet.select (false) stopped working mysteriously

Tags: excel, vba, select, worksheet

I have 2 colleagues that uses the same excel xlsm file I have written for them, and have been using them peacefully for over 1 year.

Today one of them come to me and reported his excel macro malfunctioned(it used to work), in one of the step it was supposed to select several worksheets and operate at once however now it only works on the active worksheet. I have him send his file to me and the other colleague, but it is working totally fine on the other colleagues machine and my machine. Colleague who reported problem have same Office 2013 version as me and the other colleague (macro working fine) had an older Office version.

I am doing step debug using msgbox, and saw that in the step

```
for n = a to b
msgbox
currentworkbook.sheet(n).select (false)
msgbox
next
```

the select method is not working, whislt if I change to (true), it works. Has anyone face problem such as this? Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724223/thisworkbook-sheets1-select-false-not-working

Comment: @Jordan Yes Thankyou, happened to me about the same time